# Artificial Intelligence to Detect ELL worthy questions

Tags: feature-request, ell

Having successfully transitioned from being an English language learner to an appreciator of the language, I am part of both the ELL and this stack exchange. And I am proud to be part of both vibrant communities.

However, in the recent days, I have noticed an increasingly large amount of question about basic syntax and vocabulary, that are clearly better addressed in the ELL forums. While the mods have been great at their migration duties, it is not enough; they are mere mortals after all, and there is a massive influx of these questions.

I propose an automated system to detect whether this question could be an ELL worthy question, or an English Stack question. How would this be done? Well, there are key terms that tend to appear more frequently in one area than the other. This might not have to do with the complexity of involved words, or the correctness of the user's syntax (although those could be secondary decision features). Take the word parachute. An English learner might ask about its parts of speech, and its meaning/ definition. An appropriate question here would be concerning the historical phonetics of the word, or its etymology and evolution. These key words are more likely to be in questions relevant to this site. We can train our AI model on sample questions.

No system is perfect, but we need a way to sort the questions before they are out, and not after. Then we can turn our focus to truly enjoying the nuances that the English language offers for us here.

Cheers

Comment: What does ELL think of this proposal?

Comment: Lets not send those questions to ELL. If you can make such an AI system, use it to tell people to go read a dictionary or take an English class.

Comment: Humans do it better.

Comment: This [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497935/baby-due-date-expected-on-or-in) is very simple, how would any automatic system identify it as such? There's a risk that the software ignores typos and grammar error and fixates on typical phrases and expressions used by non native speakers, then we're entering discriminatory territory. I hope this AI system, which some users might think is the solution to LQAs, doesn't see the light of day.

Comment: The AI doesn't have to migrate stuff immediately; it could just strongly suggest doing so or auto-flagging it for human mode review.

Comment: @Mari-LouA For example, the "should I say this or that" is unlikely to appear in too many ELU posts. Nothing is flawless, but we need a system to preserve the integrity, and identity of both sites.

Comment: @ab2 If it does not generate sufficient debate and interest here, there is no point taking it to ELL.

Comment: Two questions of mine using the words "should I say...?" https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A44619+%22should+I+say%22  worthy of ELL?

Comment: I agree with you. Such appearances might pose difficulty to a software. However, also note the use of the words "history" and "origin", which are more likely present in questions here. And you can find tons of ELL questions with the words history and origin, I'm aware, but

Comment: 1) The model will be based on a computer analysis of questions and answers, not on any standards that I or anyone else sets

Comment: 2) I don't intend it as a definite means of classification, just a tool that narrows the search down for our hardworking mods

Comment: @Mari-LouA You can spot an ELL question within seconds. You can do this based on (as often as not) subconscious heuristics. Machine learning works the same way, and can do the same thing: it would never confuse one of your Qs with an ELL q. Sure, “should I say” is a clue in one direction, but the length, organization, vocabulary, etc, of the Q are much stronger clues in another direction. This doesn’t confuse people, and won’t confuse machines.

Comment: @DanBron Detecting “ELL questions” is not the same thing as detecting questions that should be migrated. We have had multiple instances of people insisting that a simple looking question be migrated from ELL to ELU because it turned out to be more interesting than certain folks expect of questions from learners. I would hate to see something that looked simple in pattern but raised interesting questions for serious English enthusiasts automatically put into a rejection queue subject to band-wagoning.

Comment: @ColleenV I understand what you’re saying and I am separating “detecting ELL Qs”, and “acting on that detection”. That said, I think the risk of “losing diamonds in the rough” is far and overwhelmed by “being drowned in the rough”. It just doesn’t happen that often (I can tell you from experience). But I understand the actual motivation is not to have ELL flooded with trash. I don’t want that either.

Comment: @DanBron Every site needs help with the low quality question issue unfortunately :/ I wonder how the wizard is working on Stack Overflow. I think better detection of relevant already asked questions from the text being put into the wizard would be a better use of AI to combat the problem. The querant gets an answer without having to post and wait. Win-win.

Comment: @ConfusedSoul by any mean, anyone is free to create this AI and present the result on meta (like on Meta SO: [Can a machine be taught to flag comments automatically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280546)). From there, let the community evaluate if it is worthy for the site.

Comment: @JJJ do machines care? Do machines make sacrifices for their families? Do machines make decisions based on what is "right" or "wrong"? Do machines think? Do machines spontaneously create art? Do machines laugh?

Comment: We are much more than complex neural networks..

Comment: @JJJ `Let's not pretend it's more though` if you don't mind, I will. It's not pretending, my experience is based on what I see, feel, think and know.

Comment: I suppose if you sustain that ANN is more efficient than human thought, creativity and compassion, we might as well "man" the review queue with a software programme. I see the same 4 or 5 users close voting posts mechanically.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your thought process, and mine, are merely combinations of electric currents across biological pathways. The only difference is the computer has wires instead of neurons, and hasn't had the force of nature developing it for the past billion years or so

Comment: No two human thought processes are the same, unlike a computer. We purchase identical computers so we can rely on reliable and predictable performances. But each and every human is unique, we all have unique personalities, as do the majority of animals. The "difference" is not down to  wires vs. neurons. This is, I would have thought, pretty standard knowledge.

Comment: We seem to have entered a philosophical debate on the merits of biology and artificial intelligence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA your intuition is correct. The ideas that artificial neural networks are just simplified or under-trained representations of the human brain are just wrong. The rules by which our neural networks are constructed and our neurons trigger are encoded in our DNA (not the nets themselves) so our brain’s connections and “firing” won’t be the same even if our environment is. Humans forget and misremember things, but not randomly or disjointedly. Then there are things like Glial cells. We can use some observations we make to solve problems, but we don’t really understand human cognition.

Comment: @JJJ I didn’t say that AI won’t ever match humans. I said that viewing human cognition as the result of a complex neural network is wrong. This is like physics before the atom. It’s a useful approximation, but it’s limited.

Answer (score 3):

Questions should only be migrated if they are both off-topic for the site and on-topic on another site, so not only would the AI have to detect whether it was off-topic here, it would need to detect whether it was on-topic on ELL.

ELL tolerates questions with less research because it's hard to ask a question in a language you're still learning. It's a lot easier for us to help learners get their question into shape if they ask directly on ELL, because putting a migrated question on hold rejects it.

A better use of AI would be detecting whether someone asking is likely to be someone learning English as a foreign language, and then leaving a comment directing them to ELL where their questions might be better received.

What's the point of migrating a low quality question? Migrations are really confusing for new users, especially if they don't already have an account on ELL. Migration should be used for questions where there is something of value to preserve, like clarifications in the comments, or where the question has plenty of context and detail, not for one line "which word do I use?" questions.

Migrations, in my opinion, should never be done without human involvement. The rules aren't clear enough that we can get people to agree more often than not on what should or shouldn't be migrated or closed, and standards change as the community changes. Computers are not good at judgement calls and interpretation; they're good at detecting patterns and there's no clear pattern for questions that are off-topic on EL&U and on-topic on ELL.

I created a query to look at ELU to ELL questions. If you set the minimum to -50 you should get all the migrations that haven’t been roomba’ed yet. I like to set the minimum to 3, which represents a decent amount of engagement with the question by the ELL community. The default start date is when the migration path opened, but more representative results would probably be restricted to just the past year. Be sure to run the query against ELL. The default is Stack Overflow, and we don’t migrate many questions there.

https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/485239/migrated-questions-from-elu-with-scores-less-than-parameter?StartDate=09%2F22%2F2015&MaximumScore=50&MinimumScore=-50

In the past year, we had about 613 migrations and only 17% of the migrations have a score of 2 or higher after migration. I don’t think that is a great success rate, but not terrible considering that only 2.8% were scored negatively. The stats include rejected migrations and those closed as duplicates (that’s not a rejection). I’d have to do more work to sort out the rejections.

Comment: Presumably the ML method would be trained on questions that were 1) successfully closed to be migrated to ELL -and- 2) accepted on ELL (or not subsequently closed there as offtopic). The whole point would be to use criteria that would make both sides happy.

Comment: Not that bad m in favor of the process. If such items were put in a special queue for humans to have final say then maybe. But then why stop at 'migrate to ELL'. Train it for all close reasons.

Comment: @Mitch I don’t agree that if a migration wasn’t rejected, it was successful. There are many migrated questions on ELL that are nothing but noise (but overall migration is a positive right now). Automating migrations/reducing their cost is unlikely to improve anything. Automating low quality closures would be better. We can’t close every question here that merits it, so it’s unclear to me why anyone would think that ELL could manage to reject every poor migration.

Comment: I thought a migration to ELL had to be approved by ELL people somehow. If the migration is automatic, then yes that is a bad training method. Possibly train then on what is in general closed in ELL. The process should always take into account what is good for ELL.

Comment: I get some of the points argued against automation. However if you check the recent questions on this site, you will, at any given time, find a large quantity that are unsuitable for ELU. Sometimes, they are poorly formulated, even for ELL questions, but the fact remains that no modification can make them appropriate for this site. The final say can be human, but I see it is urgent to introduce a system that systematically identifies such quesitons.

Comment: @ConfusedSoul unsuitable for ELU does not mean they’re suitable for ELL. If they’re off-topic, close them.

Comment: @Mitch most rejected migrations that I’ve seen should have been closed here for lack of research/context/detail. I have a SEDE query that can be used to dig into migrations and how they’re received. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: @ColleenV {"captcha":true} is what I got form the SEDE. Any idea on what I should do? Also, I am aware that unsuitable for ELU doesn't imply suitable for ELL, I'm focusing on the particular class of questions and influx of many new users who seek the ELL site, and must be guided there as effectively as possible.

Comment: @ConfusedSoul log into data.stackexchange.com first then go to the url. If that doesn’t help, it’s probably browser settings? I disagree that migrations are the most effective way to guide people to ELL, particularly automated ones. Migration is very confusing and non-intuitive for new users. The most effective way is a kind comment explaining why they will get a more helpful answer on ELL. A comment allows them to ask questions of the person guiding them so they better understand why ELL is a better match.

Comment: Migrations seem to be overwhelmingly well received. As the situation stands, I can't see any helpful comments guiding these users. In the past 6 hours for example, we have three questions that can be reformatted for ELL (I admit they are poor as they are, but they can never work here, any improvement will send them to ELL). Links are: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/498014/use-of-any-in-front-of-a-singular-noun      https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497988/the-definite-article-in-specific-contexts.7

Comment: Finally, our AI can be instructed to provide helpful comments and guidance to send them to the ELL; it does not have to be a faceless bot of exiling doom :p

Comment: ELL has always said "do not migrate crap" or words to that effect, with AI that would become  inevitable. Even if candidate questions were reviewed for migration, we all know that 97% of users in the review queue would agree with migration.

Answer (score -1):

After reading the link "https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/485239/migrated-questions-from-elu-with-scores-less-than-parameter?StartDate=09%2F22%2F2015&MaximumScore=50&MinimumScore=-50" that Andrew provided, I noticed that such an idea perhaps might be feasible.

I understand many of your concerns about mass-migration and destroying valuable content, however I believe we can work together to set a system that balances precision with efficiency.

To that end, I will begin exploring options to develop a prototype of an ML based classifier (starting with something like Bayesian statistics). Ultimately, the AI will show us what it can offer, and we the community will be the final judges.

Whoever has any suggestions or input, please do comment them. Upvote this answer if you support the development of a text classifying bot.

Comment: Upvoted. Suggest you turn it into a chatbot like SmokeDetector. That is, it doesn’t take any direct action, simply posts in chat when it sees a close-worthy Q, and let’s the community make a decision.

Comment: Thanks... I'll see the options for adopting an open source neural network, but I certainly do not have the means or the experience to create one on my own. I'll check the link.

Comment: The link that Andrew provided?